# JavaScript submit button display lightbox based on radio selection

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to create a while if else (correct term?) statement. This is how its supposed to work.

When the user clicks on my submit button after selecting a particular radio button a lightbox is displayed. A lightbox with a different image is displayed based on which radio button is selected. Here is the code I've been working on to try and get this to work.

```
var RadioFieldID1 = 1,
    RadioFieldID2 = 2,
    RadioFieldID3 = 3,
    RadioFieldID4 = 4,
    smart = 5,
    dumb = 6,
    average = 7,
    idk = 8;


while(input.$submit_btn) {


if(RadioFieldID1 == smart) {

}
else if(RadioFieldID1 < smart) {

}
else {

 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said, it doesn't sound like you need to do a while-loop. Wire your button to an onclick event so something like

```
<button id="mybutton" onclick="showLightBox()" />
```

and in the the javascript you have

```
function showLightBox(){
    //normal code to display your image
}
```

Comment: What "normal code to display my image" do I need? I have an onClick attached to my submit button. Should I take that out of that and put it under that comment?

Comment: Well, you haven't given too much information on how your image is being pulled up. You could have the image already loaded but have the css set to "display: none", and on the click do `document.getElementById(imageId).style.display = 'block';`